# Filtered runable fat .jar in maven with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm currently moving a small project in to Maven and I am having some trouble.

The setup is as follows

Where a setting file is used in a my resource folder for running the application in eclipse. But when i create a fat jar the setting file is packed in side the jar. I want to filter the setting file so it is outside the jar (I understand this makes the file brittle, but that is by design) and still have it available to the application from the same folder as the jar. I have achieved this with an eclipse runnable jar and and Ant file. But I cannot seem to get it to work with maven. Any insight you have would be very useful.

Her are examples of my plugin and filter file.  Any Ideas on this would be great as this has been driving me insane

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <filters>
      <filter>src/assembly/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>ie.business.project.artifact</mainClass>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and my filter

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>distribution</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats> 
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>settings.ini</source>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </file>
  </files> 
</assembly>
```

Comment: You know that the `filter.properties` could only contain property definition which are used to replace values? See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html

Comment: then how do i filter the file from the jar?

Answer (score 1):

So I have tired something else. If I define an exclusion in my jar-plugin in addition to using maven-assembly, the setting file dose not end up in the fat jar. I'm unsure if this is the right way to do this but it has worked.

Please let me know if there in a better way to do this.

I added the following plugin to my pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
       <excludes>
          <exclude>setting.ini</exclude>
       </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using the assembly plugin pointing to the assembly in your question. If you look at the plugin configuration you are using:

```
<descriptorRefs>
  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

Actually you should be pointing to the relative path of the assembly file, like e.g:

```
<configuration>
    <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
</configuration>
```

Now the assembly file for the creation of a fat jar should be changed to create the fat jar and exclude some files. This example is just to give you an idea:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>settings.ini</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Hi Gil, thank you so much for the example i had not realised that the ids were tied in such a way. Your example has helped lots, but I still failed to  achieve what I wanted with just assembly

Comment: Congratulations for getting this to work. I have up-voted your response.